# Magento products show up in root categories

Tags: magento

After re-uploading all my products using magento API, all products from the sub categories show up in their patent categories although they are not selected to be there.

I have no idea what this is and cannot remember if we did some hack/tweak to have these products to show in their root categories.

How can I solve this?

Even more annoying is that they show up before the products that are in the main categories.

Let's say the list should look like this:

```
product1
product2
product3
```

but its like this

```
productfromsubcat1
productfromsubcat2
productfromsubcat3
product1
product2
product3
```

Comment: I think this is standard behavior.

Comment: Yes it is :/ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/79685/P15/

Comment: So, what can i do to get arround this? Is makes no sense to have it like this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to mark the categories as NOT anchor categories. I also think this disables filtering but I cannot say for certain. (I don't have an environment to test on right now)

Comment: This thread should help: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/vie/viewthread/12261/